# What is the best way to represent density in matplotlib without using color?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, data-visualization

I'm trying to represent cosine similarity among documents on a plot. I have different types of documents, which are represented by different colors. I'd like to represent the density of points, but since color identifies the type of document, I would prefer not to change the color with density. Right now, I have four different colors and it is important that red and green are shown; I will have 6 colors in the future. My main objective is to make the data as legible as possible like the following: [image: Figure 1]

While this is easy to do for plots with sparse data, it is more difficult when data points are more concentrated like below (note that the red point is no longer visible):

[image: Figure 2]

I'd be interested in hearing any best practices or suggestions as to how to best represent this data. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should sort your data according to theier sparseness, plotting more sparse data above denser data. Also, I typically use open cirlces:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.random.randn(1000,1)
y1 = np.random.randn(1000,1) # dense data
x2 = np.random.randn(100,1)
y2 = np.random.randn(100,1)
x3 = np.random.randn(10,1)
y3 = np.random.randn(10,1) # sparse data

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])

# plot sparse data after dense data
ax.scatter(x1, y1, c='none', edgecolors='blue')
ax.scatter(x2, y2, c='none', edgecolors='green')
ax.scatter(x3, y3, c='none', edgecolors='red')
```

Don't forget to play with the colors and consider using the `alpha` keyword for transparancy, if your backend supports this.

[image: Sparse and dense data, colored by category]